# Would like to understand why was my question closed

Tags: discussion

The [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/315278/why-is-git-pull-throws-an-error-cannot-be-used-without-a-working-tree) is about a hosted GIT on a Windows Server 2003. It's a centralized server that holds our CVS for 14 developers.
I think it answers and follows the FAQ guidelines, and I would like to know if I can't ask it in ServerFault - where is the place to do it?

Could I asked it in a different way ?

And if Super User is the one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea why this was closed.. I've voted to reopen it.

Comment: It's open again.

Answer (score 5):

**Obligatory Obvious Answer**:

5 people though it should be closed, and a plurality of them for the reason of "off topic"

**Honest thoughts**:

Seems like a valid question, though you have provided minimal details. We really need to know what software you're running, and the detail logs or error messages you're seeing. It seems your competiency level with system administration is rather low and you haven't demonstrated much that you put much effort into solving the issue before posting it on SF.

**I recommend**:

1. Check the logs, turn on verbose logging or reporting (commonly using the `-v` switch).
2. Edit in more details of what's going on, the exact software/platform/etc.
3. Make sure you're Googled some of the error messages, this might be a common problem. If it's easily solved by Google then it *generally is* off topic here.

Also, don't be afraid of the [FAQ](https://serverfault.com/faq) and [How to Ask a Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/how-to-ask). They're helpful.

Comment: Agreed.  The question as worded sounds more like a client issue than anything to do with servers.

Comment: thanks all, I did googled, no luck. I edited the question, hopefully to get an answer. Thanks